# How to fix game in pygame converted to exe by cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, cx-freeze

So I have made a game with PyGame which, whenever you lose a life, exits main() and since main() is at the end of the code it restarts it, but when I froze it every time I lose a life it closes. Any tips on how to deal with this?

Comment: You mean you want to restart the program when exits main()?

Comment: Please provide a [example].

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, when freezing a python program make sure to use sys.exit() and not just exit(), otherwise it won't work.